# Как разрешить модель-представление в PRISM

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, unity-container

Всем привет!
Использую Prism c Unity ioc.
Есть две модели-представления. Как можно обращаться к ним через Unity, внутри каждой модели-представления? Есть интерфейс IContainerExtension и метод Resolve. Но разрешить что то не получается. Может подскажите, как правильно это сделать.

Допустим я хочу изменить в модели-представление vm1 свойство a, из модели-представления vm2. В конструкторе vm2 пытаюсь резолвить vm1 так:

```
public vm2(IContainerExtension ce)
{
   var vm = ce.Resolve<vm1>();
   vm.a = "blablabla";
}
```

, однако во вьюхе к которой привязана vm1 значение не обновляется.

В принципе, я решил это через eventagregator, но в том же mef импорт моделей-представлений осуществлялся без проблем.

upd.

в общем я понадеялся конечно на встроенный провайдер. 
решил следующим образом.
зарегистрировал отдельно ViewModel

```
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton(typeof(vm1));            
    }
```

и привязал ее отдельно в конфигураторе ViewModelLocationProvider

```
    protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
    {
        base.ConfigureViewModelLocator();
       ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<v1>(()=> Container.Resolve<vm1>());

    }
```

в этом случае эта модель-представления прекрасно разрешается в другой модели-представлении. Не знаю только, гламурный ли это подход. Что подскажите, коллеги?

Comment: Добавьте свой код в вопрос для наглядности.

Comment: допустим я хочу изменить в модели-представление vm1 свойство a, из модели-представления vm2. в конструкторе vm2 пытаюсь резолвить vm1 так: public vm2(IContainerExtension  ce){  var vm = ce.Resolve<vm1>(); vm.a = "blablabla";}   однако во вьюхе к которой привязана vm1 значение не обновляется. в принципе я решил это через eventagregator, но в том же mef импорт моделей-представлений осуществлялся без проблем.

Comment: А `ce.Resolve<vm1>` один и тот же экземпляр возвращает, что у вас и в GUI привязан?

Comment: Как вы регистрировали vm1? Там по умолчанию транзиентный менеджер и на каждый Resolve создаётся новый экземпляр

Comment: да, точно на каждый Resolve создается отдельный объект модели-представления, ни коим образом не связанный со вьюхой. я то как раз понадеялся на дефолтный менеджер и отдельно модель-представления не регистрировал.